# Can't access variable

Tags: typescript, stripe-payments

```
pay(amount){
    var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
      key: 'public stripe key',
      locale: 'auto',
      token: function (token: any) {
        // You can access the token ID with `token.id`.
        // Get the token ID to your server-side code for use.
        this.stripeToken = token.id;
      }
    });

    console.log('token is ' + this.stripeToken);

    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: amount * 100
    });

    console.log(this.stripeToken + ' again')
  }
```

I can't access the this.stripeToken variable outside of the the token function for some reason.  When i try to console.log() it with the 'token is' + stripeToken or this.stripetoken + 'again', I just get an undefined for the variable.  The stripe variable is declared like this:
public stripeToken: any;
at the top of the component.ts page this is a part of.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

> I can't access the this.stripeToken variable outside of the the token function for some reason.

That's because it doesn't exist yet. The token function will be called asynchronously sometime in the future, but your log statements are happening immediately. If you have code that needs to use the token, you should put it into the callback function.

```
var handler = (<any>window).StripeCheckout.configure({
  key: 'pk_test_51HX4yUDEnGCSjwlXYRIFs3Wj9fFXw8DW7kLUacKFKPIcC0P96E6C4I9kVku5brUOGR33O2KKH6NkfIawr3oo11eU00eL9q8lAk',
  locale: 'auto',
  token: function (token: any) {
    // Put your code that uses the token here
  }
});
```

Comment: So i tried calling my this.storeService.testOrder(token) in that callback, but it comes back with saying the function doesn't exist.  I can call it outside of that function though.

Comment: If you're trying to access `this` in a callback function, then you can't use a regular function. Simplest fix is to use an arrow function: `token: (token: any) => { /* your code here * }`. You could also bind the regular function if you prefer.

Answer (score 0):

This is because the `token` will most probably execute async. You can use a subject to trigger the whole thing if you need.

```js
import {
  Subject
} from 'rxjs';

pay(amount) {
  const token$ = new Subject();

  token$.subscribe((token) => {
    console.log('token is ' + token);

    handler.open({
      name: 'Demo Site',
      description: '2 widgets',
      amount: amount * 100
    });

    console.log(token + ' again')
  })

  var handler = ( < any > window).StripeCheckout.configure({
    key: 'pk_test_51HX4yUDEnGCSjwlXYRIFs3Wj9fFXw8DW7kLUacKFKPIcC0P96E6C4I9kVku5brUOGR33O2KKH6NkfIawr3oo11eU00eL9q8lAk',
    locale: 'auto',
    token: function(token: any) {
      token$.next(token.id);
    }
  });
}
```